# Memory leak in NSJSONSerialization method?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

This is my code:

```
response.responseObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
```

There are 1030 leaks (70.23 KB) in this line of code as stated by Instruments. Is it possible the leak can be somewhere else?

Comment: Will changing to NSURLSession eliminate the problem?

Comment: I have some leaks in response.appendData(data) method as well

Comment: did you found any solution to resolve memory leak?